# Can a person who gained immunity to a disease become an infectious carrier?

Tags: biology, humans, diseases, medical, isolation

If a person is sent out of their hermetically sealed community and in the process becomes immune to a deadly disease. When the person returns will the immunity make them a carrier and infect/kill all of the non-immune citizens?

How would they quarantine and deal with that possibility?

Comment: So you want Typhoid Mary.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a difference between being a carrier and being immune.

Comment: The immunity can't be infections, but a person who's beating the disease and developing immunity still has pathogens and can infect others, for some time.

Comment: Title does not match question, which leaves me a bit confused as to what you are asking.  Regarding the title alone, there have been stories which proposed fighting a virus with a virus, or something similar.  An example is the TV series Last Ship.  I don't know if this passes the reality-check though.

Comment: I'm a bit foggy on the details, did Typhoid Mary ever become immune?

Comment: @Cherry Typhoid Mary was, as far as anyone could tell, always immune, that was the problem

Answer (score 15):

The scenario may be possible, there is a thing called an [Asymptomatic Carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptomatic_carrier), the most famous being [Typhoid Mary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Mallon), these people have a disease that doesn't effect them but they can still pass it on to others. As I understand it any disease, whether viral or bacterial, can have asymptomatic carriers, I know people can be asymptomatic carriers of the mumps virus as well as typhus bacteria.

Quarantine measures in these cases are tricky, no-one, even the carrier knows that they're sick until *after* the people around them start dropping, and it can be very hard to tie the disease to a specific source, delaying quarantine implementation further. In the case of Typhoid Mary they eventually had to jail her because they couldn't convince her that she was making people she cooked for ill. Depending on the [latency period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incubation_period), how long it takes between host infection and the first symptoms of the disease, [virulence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virulence), the speed and efficiency with which the disease spreads and it's [lethality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethality) by the time they know that they *need* a quarantine they could all be dying.

Comment: Assuming that this society is incredibly vigilant and they quarantine her right away. If she has finished developing her immunity would she be able to rejoin the community without causing harm?

Comment: @Cherry Nope the whole problem with asymptomatic carriers is that they are _already_ immune to the disease they're carrying but their body doesn't kill the disease completely so they make people around them sick without a clear cause.